# How to use WebUI.getUrl().contains('atlassian') with timeout value

Tags: katalon-studio

I have a piece of code that has a 5 sec delay and getUrl after. If I dont delay the execution, getUrl returns false since the site doesn't load yet.

```
WebUI.delay(5)
assert WebUI.getUrl().contains('atlassian')
```

In the website, there is a div which leads to another window when clicked. This code checks if the opened page is an Atlassian webpage. However, I don't want to use delay for 5 sec(it may take way longer or shorter). Is there a way to put a timeout, for instance wait for 1 min until page loads and if not loaded -> fail execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try waiting for page load

```
WebUI.waitForPageLoad(5, FailureHandling.STOP)
assert WebUI.getUrl().contains('atlassian')
```

This will wait for 5 seconds for the page load and stop execution with test failed if the page isn't loaded in that time.

Alternatively, you could use `WebUI.waitForElementPresent(to, timeout)` where `to` is a test object you are certain is present when the page is loaded.

Comment: No problem! That's what SO is for.